# How to get the instance of the ControlTemplate not the template child instance in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight

I want to get the instance of the ControlTemplate through

```
Validation = GetTemplateChild("ValidationToolTipTemplate") as ControlTemplate;
```

In Generic.xaml I have this code:

```
 <ControlTemplate x:Key="ValidationToolTipTemplate"> </ControlTemplate>

 <Style TargetType="local:DateTimeControl">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
               <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:DateTimeControl">
                  //code goes here
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

I can access all the template child that is within the Control template(ControlTemplate TargetType="local:DateTimeControl").

But I also wanted to get the instance of the ***ControlTemplate x:Key="ValidationToolTipTemplate"***

Is it possible to get the instance?

Comment: Why do you want to access the tamplate? I bet what you really need has nothing to do with accessing the template...

Comment: with the help of this I'm showing the tooltip

Comment: I have solved this will post the answer